# Binary file to blob column population using Jython

Tags: jython

I want to populate a database table having blob column with the content of a binary file that will be placed on the server.The name of the file  will not be constant and will keep on varying .Is this possible in Jython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy:

```
def insert_file_to_db(db_url, usr, passwd, file_name):
    db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
    blob = FileInputStream(file_name)
    pstm = db.prepareStatement("insert into my_blobs (content) values (?)")
    pstm.setBinaryStream(1, blob)
    rs = pstm.execute()
    blob.close()
```

(tested with Informix JDBC driver)